# Can not delete unSelected dates from array in material calendar view

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using material calendar view in my android project. I am adding the selected date in array using the date method 'setOnDateChangedListener' and here is the code of my function

```
 materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode(MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    materialCalendarView.setCurrentDate(today);
    materialCalendarView.state().edit()
            .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(today))
            .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(calendar))
            .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS)
            .commit();

 materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull final MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull final CalendarDay date, final boolean selected) {


            for(int i=0;i<widget.getSelectedDates().size();i++)
            {

                my_Dates1.add(date.getDay());

            }

            Log.e("Datess", String.valueOf(my_Dates1));


        }
    });
```

i want to remove a date from array if it is 'unSelected' from the calendar. There is a boolean selected, Can anybody tell me how i remove a date from array if it is 'unSelected' form the calendar using select variable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No body helped me. But I solved problem on my own. Using the below code.

Comment: if (selected)
                            {
                                my_Dates1.add(date.getDate());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                my_Dates1.remove(date.getDate());
                            }

Comment: what is myDate1 coming from?